# How to use aliases in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, alias

Simple question: How to use aliases after SELECT statement? Let's say i have query like this:

```
SELECT salary/12 AS sal 
FROM sdatabase
WHERE sal > 1000
```

Of course it won't work because database will throw me an error. I know I can just replace `sal` with `salary/12` like this:

```
WHERE salary/12 > 1000
```

but I think it is less readable. So is there anything I can do with it or this is just the way it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, `WHERE` clause is calculated before `SELECT`. That's why you cannot use column `sal` in `WHERE`. It's not like in other languages where code is executed from top to bottom. A simplified order looks like this:

1. FROM
2. JOIN
3. WHERE
4. GROUP BY
5. HAVING
6. SELECT
7. DISTINCT
8. ORDER BY

You can find more information about it by typing `logical query processing` in your browser.

Comment: Are you aware of any resources that explain why the language was originally designed to evaluate the clauses in a different order to which they are written?

Comment: You can read this article written by Itzik Ben-Gan -> https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you He writes about sql server, but the principles are the same.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the original query up as a *derived table* (subquery):

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT salary/12 AS sal
    FROM sdatabase
) dt
WHERE sal > 1000
```

Comment: I guess it comes down to personal preference, but this is much less readable to me than just using salary/12 in a where clause.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson, well salary/12 isn't perhaps the best example. But when it comes to more complex expressions, a derived table like this makes the code easier to write, and less risky to update!

Comment: i agree with jarth this way is best for readablity +1 for that.. @HoneyboyWilson but still advice you to write `SELECT salary/12 AS sal 
FROM t
WHERE salary/12 > 1000` as i believe most SQL optimizers would see that jarth's query condition `WHERE sal > 1000` can be pushed down into the inner select annyway .. MySQL 8.0 [optimizer](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oBBXb9dZsnmZrNtAwiBmmk/0) for example rewites it into `select (test.sdatabase.salary / 12) AS sal from test.sdatabase where ((test.sdatabase.salary / 12) > 1000)` <- notice the derived table (subquery) is gone..

Answer (score 0):

From a chronological stand point your alias is not available in the "WHERE", so you need  a subQuery to achieve this...

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT salary/12 AS sal FROM sdatabase ) 
sq WHERE sal > 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Common Table Expression (CTE) -

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT salary/12 AS sal 
FROM sdatabase
WHERE sal > 1000)

SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE sal > 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning How to use Alias in WHERE statement, Then @Jarlh's solution is fine but in practical, using the filter condition directly as below make more sense. This exclude use of a sub-query with the same result.

```
SELECT salary/12 AS sal 
FROM sdatabase
WHERE salary > 12000
```